# Run Xcode 5 project in Xcode 6 in ios

Tags: ios, xcode6, xcode5.1

i have created universal project using Xcode 5. Now how can I run those project in Xcode 6.
Also want to upgrade for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.

```
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
//#define IS_IPHONE_6PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] nativeScale] == 3.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6_PLUS (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
```

Comment: Just open the project in Xcode 6 add the necessary launch images to assets catalog or use the new Launch Screen file.

Comment: @rckoenes I'm facing problem in simulator. Not able to get proper size for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus over simulator.

Comment: have you added the correct launch images in the assets catalog or are you using the new Launch Screen file?

Comment: i have added launch image over asset catalog but when i run for iPhone 6 and 6 plus its print 568X320 which is iPhone 5 size

Comment: Are you sure the images are the correct size? Post your where you create the `UIWindow`

Comment: @rckoenes you want to see Asset catalog ?

Comment: I'll believe you ;) But other then that I can't think of anything else.

Comment: thanks but you may try this. Check wether this Creates problem OR not. Run Xcode 5.0.1 project in Xcode 6.0.1 and print simulator iPhone 6 and 6 plus size ?

Comment: The size 568X320 is returned when running in compatibility mode. Meaning that there are no correct launch images found. So for the iPhone 6 I get 667 X 667

Comment: i have made some change above . Are above define check are right ?

Comment: i have created new launch image in Image.xcassets but still printing iPhone 5 size

Comment: Just use: `[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];` it is really wrong to detect the phone by it screen size and also not needed. Use autolayout to setup your UI correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Jorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26220005/2998) says, don't work with specific size screens. It should be pretty obvious given recent events that Apple no longer feel constrained by a small number of screen sizes.

To make your app work on iPhone 6 and 6+, you need to add a Launch Screen file, either a XIB or a storyboard that looks like your first screen (or a splash screen). Much like the iPhone 5-size image tells Xcode that your app supports the iPhone 5, the launch screen tells Xcode that your app has been updated for the most recent phones.

Note that you might also need to make other changes. The iOS 8 SDK has plenty of changes others than the screen sizes.

Comment: Sir how can I use add launching image using Launch Screen ?

Comment: A quick Google came up with: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

Answer (score 2):

Do not base your code on screen resolution. Available features should be detected by `respondsToSelector:`, UI should be done using auto layout and if you need to do some customization for certain sizes, use the size class control in Xcode. If you need to do this in code, use `willTransitionToTraitCollection(:withTransitionCoordinator:)` to find out which size class that will appear.

See Apple's introduction to size classes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-DontLinkElementID_1)